# Simplifying expectation of square of sum

Tags: probability, statistics, information-theory

I am working on a problem (not for homework) where one step involves simplifying an expectation. The solution looks like this:

Call $p_\mu(X)$ the PDF of the variable distributed as $N(\mu, \sigma^2I)$. Let $E_0$ denote the expectation under $N(0, \sigma^2I)$.

Then $E_0\left[\left(1+q\left(\frac{p_\mu(X) - p_0(X)}{p_0(X)}\right)\right)^2\right] = 1+q^2E_0\left[\left(\frac{p_\mu(X) - p_0(X)}{p_0(X)}\right)^2\right]$.

I'm not able to derive this step; I tried expanding the square and am left with a middle term that does not seem to equal zero. I also tried using $E[X^2] = Var(X) + E[X]^2$ which also left me with extra terms. Am I missing an identity here?

For context, the full solution is 6.2b here: http://web.stanford.edu/class/stats311/Exercises/2019-solutions.pdf

Comment: I'm guessing you're doing on of the free online courses? Can you link to the question as well as the solution, that context might help (is this related to the Kullback–Leibler divergence), or there may be a typo. From the look of things that statement is equivalent to $$E_{0}[p_{\mu}(X)] = 0$$, though if I'm interpreting the terms correctly this should be greater than zero unless the probability distributions don't overlap.

Comment: Yes exactly.. The full question is 6.2(b) here http://web.stanford.edu/class/stats311/lecture-notes.pdf#page=108&zoom=100,96,677 but it is fairly involved and I was hoping to not make people sift through the entire question. (It is Renyi divergence in this case, not KL divergence.) He uses the same identity (?) for proving both inequalities so it seems unlikely to be a typo...

Comment: Realised I was looking at the linear term from the wrong quadratic, which means the statement is actually $$E_{0} \left[\frac{p_{\mu}(X) - p_{0}(X)}{p_{0}(X)}\right] = 0$$ which does makes sense. Have posted this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that the linear part looks like

$$2q E_{0} \left[ \frac{p_{\mu}(X) - p_{0}(X)}{p_{0}(X)}\right] = \int_{X} \frac{p_{\mu}(X) - p_{0}(X)}{p_{0}(X)} p_{0}(X) = \int_{X} p_{\mu}(X) - \int_{X} p_{0}(X)$$

Then since this is a difference in total probability of these two distributions it must be zero (i.e. 1-1 = 0).

Comment: Oh - of course, it's clear now. Thank you.